# netlify form submission fails onsubmit

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I am trying to use Netlify forms, I have a very simple react app with just one component "Form" that looks like this,

```
import React from 'react'

function Form() {
  return (
    <div>
          <form name="loanform" method="POST" data-netlify="true">
            <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="loanform"/>
    
                <label htmlFor="full-name">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="full-name" name="full-name"/>

                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
            
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>

          </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Form
```

I have build the app and deployed it on netlify, heres the link https://statuesque-phoenix-329a03.netlify.app/

The issue is when i click submit, i get the following error,

Page Not Found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1LuZ.png)

Comment: Is the form listed in the forms section of your Netlify Dashboard?

Comment: No it was not, i just found the solution anyway. You have to add the form's html in the body tag in the index.html too. Found it from here: https://answers.netlify.com/t/react-bootstrap-netlifys-form-not-working/72162